# Bind9 - Same Domain - Forward querries if not found in internal DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I have some servers with IP public and Private IP and domain exemple.com hosting on external DNS with a lot of entries

```
server1 IN A IpPublic
server2 IN A IpPublic
server3 IN A IpPublic
server4 IN A IpPublic
...
...
```

I want to set up an Internal DNS  for use the localIP but when the internal DNS cant resolv something then use the externalDNS

```
server1 IN A PrivateIP
server2 IN A PrivateIP
server3 IN A PrivateIP
```

I have created a zone

```
zone "exemple.com" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.exemple.com";
allow-query { any; };
};
```

and forwarders

```
 forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
 };
```

as my internal DNS is master of exemple.com he didn't forward in any case querries with *.exemple.com to my external DNS .

How I can setup bind9 for forward querries if bind9 didnt find the entry in /etc/bind/db.exemple.com

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe you can get BIND to do that by adding an authoritative (master/slave) zone.

You may want to consider delegating a sub-zone for your "local" needs, alternatively use [RPZ](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#rpz) on your resolver server as a means of overriding lookups that would normally be looked up through recursion (or forwarding).